# On logic vs information theory

Tags: logic, information-theory, philosophy, paradoxes

If the statements

> All crows are black

and

> All non black things are non crows

are equal, then why is the former so much easier to communicate by giving examples? What implications does this have on information theory?

Comment: This is called the [contrapositive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contraposition), and yes, sometimes in mathematics when trying to prove a statement, considering the contrapositive of it is much easier to prove. I definitely don't think this answers your question much at all however, so just see this as a sort of side comment.

Comment: Informally speaking, there are too many X such that a "non-black thing" is "non-X" for that information to be of any importance. In a closed world (where number of such possible X is low) seeing a red fire extinguisher indeed supports a claim that all ravens are black, which can be somewhat a problem when creating expert systems.

Comment: Another problem I have is there exist only finite crows in the first class so the statement can be given with examples. In the latter there are an infinite number of black things which are also not crows so the full message can never be communicated.

Comment: This is called [Hempel's paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raven_paradox) or the paradox of the ravens. Wikipedia's discussion is fairly extensive.  Thereis also discussion in the Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy in the articles on [Carl Hempel](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/hempel/#ParCon) and [the problem of induction](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/induction-problem/#ParRav).

Comment: thanks it's easier to research a problem with a name. though it appears as if there's no general concensus on how to deal with this paradox? Also is this a true paradox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\mathcal{U}$ be the *finite* universal set of all things under the Sun. Let $\mathcal{B}$ be the set of all black things. Let $\mathcal{C}$ be the set of all crows. Since there are non-black things and black things that are not crows, we have

$$\mathcal{C} \subset \mathcal{B} \subset \mathcal{U}$$

Suppose that a friend living far away is thinking about a thing. As this friend has many interests and thinks about many things, we are conservative and assume that the PMF of the thing being thought of is **uniform** over $\mathcal{U}$. Hence, the measure of our uncertainty regarding our friend's thought is $\log_2 |\mathcal{U}|$ bits. If our friend sends us the message

> I am thinking about a crow.

then our uncertainty has been reduced to $\log_2 |\mathcal{C}|$ bits, i.e., our friend's message contained

$$\log_2 |\mathcal{U}| - \log_2 |\mathcal{C}| = \log_2 \left(\frac{|\mathcal{U}|}{|\mathcal{C}|}\right) > 0$$

bits of information. However, if our friend sends us the message

> I am thinking about a non-black thing.

then our uncertainty has been reduced to $\log_2 (|\mathcal{U}|-|\mathcal{B}|)$ bits, i.e., our friend's message contained

$$\log_2 |\mathcal{U}| - \log_2 (|\mathcal{U}|-|\mathcal{B}|) = \log_2 \left(\frac{|\mathcal{U}|}{|\mathcal{U}|-|\mathcal{B}|}\right) > 0$$

bits of information. If there are more non-black things than crows, which is a most reasonable assumption to make, then $|\mathcal{U}|-|\mathcal{B}| > |\mathcal{C}|$ and, thus,

$$\log_2 \left(\frac{|\mathcal{U}|}{|\mathcal{C}|}\right) > \log_2 \left(\frac{|\mathcal{U}|}{|\mathcal{U}|-|\mathcal{B}|}\right)$$

i.e., the former message ("crow") contains more information than the latter one ("non-black").

Comment: Why doe this not work with infinite U, It seems the message ("crow") contains more information than the latter one ("non-black") even with an infinite universe allowing for infinite crows and infinite non black things. Even under the conditions of finite crows and infinite non-black things.

Comment: @shaihorowitz A probability mass function (PMF) over an infinite discrete set is a strange concept. Also, the Shannon entropy of a **uniform** PMF is the logarithm of the cardinality of its support. I wanted to keep things as simple as possible at first.

Comment: Are there any text recommendations to get into the concepts of A probability mass function (PMF) over an infinite discrete set? I cant imagine anything you could have said that would have made me more interested then it being a strange concept.

Comment: @shaihorowitz You may want to read about https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_entropy (for PDF's, rather than PMF's)

Answer (score 6):

This is an interesting question. Here's a stab: Let the statement be $A$. I'm considering two ways of convincing you of $A$.

- 1) Enumerate all crows, and demonstrate that each one is black.
- 2) Enumerate all non-black things, and demonstrate that each one is not a crow.

Now, there are far more non-black things than crow things. So if I give you an example where I point out a crow and demonstrate that it is black, I've made further progress towards convincing you than I would have if I pointed out a non-black thing and demonstrated that it was not a crow.

So I'm likely to choose strategy 1).

Now I'm trying to think of an example where strategy 2) is the better bet, i.e. where there are far more "crows" than there are "non-black" things.

EDIT: Mark Dominus points out that this is a thing; it's called [Hempel's Paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raven_paradox). They use ravens, but that's probably really important.

Comment: Could you give an intuitive explanation why one can be finite and therefore communicable but the second isn't because of non black things that are not crows?

Comment: @shaihorowitz: I'm not sure I buy that there necessarily are infinitely many non-black things. I suspect that depends on your definition of "thing".

Comment: I mean that because the examples are non black you can never tell if I'm talking about ravens or crows in the contrapositive by giving examples. but the forward implication easily separates the two.